# 4pin camera with audio and video pin

Tags: pins

I have found this camera from an old ATM machine.

I want to use it but I don't have any knowledge about the video pin. Where I can connect to get video output?

[image: picture of camera]

Comment: Reasonably likely to work with a TV or monitor with RCA jacks for video and sound.

Answer (score 3):

To me that camera looks like a standard analog CCTV-type camera that outputs [composite video](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_video). Lots of video equipment that accepts composite video input will do so using an [RCA connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector) to which you'd have to connect the GND and VIDEO pins seen in your pictures.